# About asp.net hosting

Tags: asp.net, hosting, configure

How do I setup and configure my asp.net site and SQL Server database when I upload it to hosting server?
Thank you
best regards.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, can you add more detail?

Comment: you want to deploy on dedicate server or shared hosting?

Comment: My site is working correctly at local host ,
simply:
What are the changes that be applied on config file when I upload it on hosting server....

Answer (score 1):

I think it really comes down to what your hosting setup is.  That will then define what configuration must take place within the ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 0):

I have my solution for this:

I have in my web.config 2 connectionstrings and in my code using directive and symbol debug i check for one or another

-#if DEBUG

is my test machine

-#else

my production server

-#endif

and put my connections strings in if, next when i compile in Release Mode it use my production server connection string